# Данные DataGridView в List

Tags: c#

Работаю с базой данных MSSQL. Есть у меня класс модели:

```
public class Plavka
    {
        public int plavka;
        public DateTime dataPrig;
        public int smena;
        public string masterFIOPrepare;
        public int nKonveera;
        public string otkFIO;
        public bool status;
        public float mBrak;
    }
```

Получаю данные из базы в список:

```
    PlCon plcon = new PlCon();
    List<Plavka> plavka = plCon.GetPlavka(); //PlCon - класс для работы с базой
```

Как мне заполнить DataGridView полученным листом ?. Так не получается:

```
public MainForm()
        {
            PlCon plcon = new PlCon();
            List<Plavka> plavka = plCon.GetPlavka();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = plavka;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы используете в своем классе поля. DataGridView по умолчанию генерирует привязку для свойств, а не для полей. Исправьте свой класс Plavka так, как это показано ниже, после чего всё сбиндится.

```
public class Plavka
{
    public int plavka { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataPrig { get; set; }
    public int smena { get; set; }
    public string masterFIOPrepare { get; set; }
    public int nKonveera { get; set; }
    public string otkFIO { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public float mBrak { get; set; }
}
```

А вообще, если по-хорошему, то код ваш ужасен. И та проблема, которую вы продемонстрировали, вытекает из того, что вы грубо нарушаете принцип инкапсуляции. Возможно, вы когда-то слышали (а если не слышали, то советую помнить об этом, поскольку это довольно важная штука) - **поля  не должны быть открытыми**. Они представляют собой детали внутренней реализации класса, а потому должны быть скрыты от пользователя.

З.Ы. А вот если бы вы использовали анонимный тип (речь идет исключительно о "если бы", на самом деле это тоже не нужно делать), то привязка прошла бы без проблем, поскольку у анонимных типов нет как таковой внутренней реализации, все их члены определяют их интерфейс

Comment: То есть биндинг работает только со свойствами, а с полями, несмотря на то, что они public, не работает?

Comment: @Freezze а вы знаете, что такое инкапсуляция, зачем она нужна, и чем поля отличаются от свойств? Да, биндинг не должен работать с полями, потому что поля не должны являться частью интерфейса класса, это очень дурная практика. Именно поэтому интерфейсы (те, что описываются ключевым словом interface) не могут содержать полей, тогда как содержать свойства они могут

Comment: @DreamChild да я знаю что такое инкапсуляция и чем отличаются поля от свойств. Спасибо за то, что тыкнули носом.
И еще я знаю что такое вежливость, возможно, в отличии от Вас.

Comment: А в чем, извиняюсь, @DreamChild был невежлив? Все очень даже корректно.

Comment: разобрался. всё было нормально. проблема оказалось в том что вылетал Exception так как одно поле возвращало DBNull, я это не учел просто.
Не знаю всех мелочей того что вы написали выще, я пока только изучаю ADO.NET, но я делал так: получаю данные в List<Plavka>, а при сохранении создаю экземпляр класса Plavka и вызываю метод отправляя ему экземпляр, который уже другими путями сохраняет это всё в базу.

Comment: Расскажите как мне следовало сделать с Анонимными типами?

Comment: >Расскажите как мне следовало сделать с Анонимными типами?

@zerpico, никак. Анонимные типы я упомянул исключительно к слову, для примера. В C# они не являются [объектами первого класса][1], а потому использование их для хранения результатов, полученных из базы данных сопряжено с определенными трудностями

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0